# Error while I run a p. benchmark with Hyperledger Caliper: No valid responses from any peers, chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I want to run a performance benchmark for the contract (which is writen in typescript) from this repository:https://github.com/AleRapchan/hyperledger-supply-chain

So, I am using Hyperledger Caliper based on this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.5.0/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/
to run the performance benchmark and I followed these steps:

Steps followed:

1. I have clonned this repo as I mentioned before: https://github.com/AleRapchan/hyperledger-supply-chain and, at the same level, I created the `caliper-workspace` folder as the tutorial said.
2. I created the channel "mychannel" and deployed the chaincode respectively.

   `./network.sh up createChannel -ca -s couchdb`

   `./network.sh deployCC -ccn supplychain -ccp ../../chaincode -ccl typescript`
3. I have configured the three caliper files as shown below (myAssetBenchmark.yaml, networkConfig.yaml, readAsset.js) into the `caliper-workspace` folder.
4. I have installed the caliper dependencies in the `caliper-workspace` folder.

   `npm install --only=prod @hyperledger/caliper-cli@0.5.0`

   `npx caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric:2.2`
5. At the same directory, I run the performance benchmark with the following command:

`npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/networkConfig.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test`

**but I got the following errors**:

**Error 1**

```
 error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
peer=peer0.org2.example.com:9051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction b6cc9ab28537a5539aa0876a823a679a952dee1232540e8efbe1ad01e02ebfbb: could not launch chaincode supplychain_1.0:a38d65123f915a15106ad4d0f8893b0880ed2979ddcc84106b9267f5ee31ddd4: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction b6cc9ab28537a5539aa0876a823a679a952dee1232540e8efbe1ad01e02ebfbb: could not launch chaincode supplychain_1.0:a38d65123f915a15106ad4d0f8893b0880ed2979ddcc84106b9267f5ee31ddd4: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
```

**Error 2**

```
error [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway]   Failed to perform submit transaction [createProduct] using arguments [1_0,1234567890,50,Fruit Juices,,2022-06-24T18:25:43.511Z,{},Apple Juice,Etobicoke, ON, Canada,2021-06-24T18:25:43.511Z,$9.00,200,ml],  with error: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=peer0.org2.example.com:9051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 5837e5ab8b41016290a3d204f4ffde53bad977e917eb1ae53784623959d4e359: could not launch chaincode supplychain_1.0:a38d65123f915a15106ad4d0f8893b0880ed2979ddcc84106b9267f5ee31ddd4: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
    peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 5837e5ab8b41016290a3d204f4ffde53bad977e917eb1ae53784623959d4e359: could not launch chaincode supplychain_1.0:a38d65123f915a15106ad4d0f8893b0880ed2979ddcc84106b9267f5ee31ddd4: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
```

**myAssetBenchmark.yaml**

```
test:
name: basic-contract-benchmark
description: test benchmark
workers:
  number: 2
rounds:
  - label: readAsset
    description: Read asset benchmark
    txDuration: 30
    rateControl:
      type: fixed-load
      opts:
        transactionLoad: 2
    workload:
      module: workload/readAsset.js
      arguments:
        assets: 10
        contractId: supplychain
```

**networkConfig.yaml**

```
name: Caliper test
version: "2.0.0"

caliper:
  blockchain: fabric

channels:
  - channelName: mychannel
    contracts:
    - id: supplychain

organizations:
  - mspid: Org1MSP
    identities:
      certificates:
      - name: 'User1'
        clientPrivateKey:
          path: '../hyperledger-supply-chain/network/fabric-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/46d82eb2dbaed33f941f9a39394bba7b5167d09d116ba563de1675f22b083d3e_sk'
        clientSignedCert:
          path: '../hyperledger-supply-chain/network/fabric-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'
    connectionProfile:
      path: '../hyperledger-supply-chain/network/fabric-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml'
      discover: true
```

**readAsset.js**

```
'use strict';

const { WorkloadModuleBase } = require('@hyperledger/caliper-core');

class MyWorkload extends WorkloadModuleBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext) {
        await super.initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext);

        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const id = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Creating asset ${id}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: 'createProduct',
                invokerIdentity: 'User1',
                contractArguments: [id, '1234567890', 50, 'Fruit Juices', [],
                '2022-06-24T18:25:43.511Z', JSON.stringify({}),'Apple Juice', 'Etobicoke, ON, Canada',
                '2021-06-24T18:25:43.511Z','$9.00', 200, 'ml'],
                readOnly: false
            };

            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }

    async submitTransaction() {
        const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.roundArguments.assets);
        const myArgs = {
            contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
            contractFunction: 'readProduct',
            invokerIdentity: 'User1',
            contractArguments: [`${this.workerIndex}_${randomId}`],
            readOnly: true
        };

        await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(myArgs);
    }

    async cleanupWorkloadModule() {
        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Deleting asset ${assetID}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: null,
                invokerIdentity: 'User1',
                contractArguments: [id],
                readOnly: false
            };

            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }
}

function createWorkloadModule() {
    return new MyWorkload();
}

module.exports.createWorkloadModule = createWorkloadModule;
```

PD: I am using WSL2 based engine (Docker Desktop and WSL2).

Comment: It looks like some sort of issue with the chaincode as it appears to be terminating based on this message `chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0`

Comment: any error in the chaincode container logs?